# Power Set and bijection

Tags: notation

everyone. I'm having a hard time doing this. In fact, I have read and reread the subject several times, but I feel unable to develop it:

In the literature, the set of parts $\operatorname{Pow}(M)$ (power set) of a set $M$ is often identified with $2^M = \{f \mid f : M \to \{0, 1\}\},$ that is, with the set
of the functions from $M$ to $\{0, 1\}.$ This is justified by the fact that there is a bijection of
$Pow(M)$ to $2^M$ (and therefore also from $2^M$ to $Pow(M)$).

Establish
functions from $Pow(M)$ to $2^M,$ and vice versa, and show that these functions are bijections!

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. You say Pow(M) is the power set, and it also "identifies with $2^M.$" Does that mean both sets are the same?

Comment: "Establishment" is a noun. You might mean "Establish," the verb?

Answer (score 2):

First, let's be clear: $2^M$ is a set of functions and $Pow(M)$ is a set of sets.

Consider $f \in 2^M$ . 
Then, consider the set $ S =\{ p \in M \hspace{3pt} | \hspace{3pt} f(p) = 1\}$. 
Note that $ S \in Pow(M) $

What I described above, is a *function* that has input $f \in 2^M$ and that outputs the corresponding $ S \in Pow(M) $.

There's a lot still to be done to finish the proof, but you should be easily be able to do that.
I'm hoping this example will help you with the concepts needed to solve your doubts.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Thank you for only giving a hint, not a full solution, to a question that [could do with more context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960). While your reputation is low you can only post answers, so I'm helping you along with a +1 here; I think at about 50 rep you'll be able to leave comments, which are even better places for hints. They can also be very short, e.g. "Hint: for $f\in2^M$ define $g(f):=\{p\in M|f(p)=1\}$".

Comment: @J.G. Thanks for the +1! I did think about leaving the hint as a comment but as you correctly identified, I am unable to comment as I have only just started on Math SE.